# When to use "?android" or "@android"?

Tags: android

I am a newbie and trying to understand the following XML code:

Looking at the documentation at developer.android.com, it says "starStyle" is a constant in R.attr and

---

public static final int starStyle
Since: API Level 1

Default Star style.

### Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".

It seems to say that there are 2 syntax I can declare.  1) "@[+][package:]type:name" 2) "?[package:][type:]name".

If there are 2 syntax, what is the correct one for "@[+][package:]type:name" ?

I tried ""@android:attr/starStyle" but I didn't get a "star" checkbox even though the application compiled ok.

Answer (score 8):

The @-syntax is used for resources that are defined in your project or the Android framework. The ?-syntax is used for resources in the current theme.

For starStyle, which should be defined in the theme, you want:

> "?android:attr/starStyle"

See [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/android_resources-i18n_ReferencesToThemeAttributes.html) for some elaboration on theme resources.

Answer (score 3):

Android provides a shortcut to enable you to

> use styles from the currently applied theme.

To do this, use `?android:` rather than @ as a prefix to the resource you want to use.

example:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myEditText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@android:string/url"
android:textColor="?android:textColor"
/>
```

This technique enables you to create styles that change if the current theme changes, without you
modifying each individual style resource.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK...

"?[package:][type:]name" refers to an Android style. 
As an example a progress dialog style attribute would look something like:

> style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"

An explanation

- ? = ?
- [package:] = android:
- [type:] = attr (attribute)
- name = progressBarStyleLarge (or in your case: starStyle)

However, styles are also referenced using the @...

"@[+][package:]type:name" is a resource of some sort.

So for a style, you would declare all your styles in a file named 'styles.xml" in your 'values' directory.

```
<style name="mono_text_headers">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Then reference them just like a string, drawable, etc.. 
`style="@style/mono_text_headers"`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for in short and simple.

> **?** represents that resource definition is a part of a **Framework**
>
> **@** represents that resource definition is a part of a Your
> **Project/Support Library**

Answer (score 1):

I checked a lot on this question for it confuse me a lot once.

The name after ? is you are referencing a Variable name that is defined in the `<declare-styleable>`.

The name after @ is the style name defined by you or system.

Let me put an analogy by C++.

Say, we have `string str1 = "Hello world"`.

? is like string `str2 = str1`. It means you are referencing the value of `str1`.

@ is like `string str2 = "Hello world"`. It means you are using the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

@ is used to access defined resources

```
"@android:drawables/test.png"
```

? is used to access defined theme style

```
"?android/attr/style"
```

Hope this helps